# Time complexity of std::find() in std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map with no collisions

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity

I know unordered_map has O(1) lookups but std::find() is a searching algorithm(I guess) in other containers.So is it O(1) or O(n) considering there is no collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) for `std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::find`:

> #### Complexity
>
> Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container.